# how generate a series of numbers by grouping the data in db2 or sql

Tags: sql, db2

I have data as below

| Manager | City | Building | Floor | Number of Seats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | BLR | SA2 | 2F | 2 |
| xyz | BLR | SA2 | 2F | 3 |
| xya | BLR | SA2 | 3F | 2 |
| xjk | BLR | SA2 | 3F | 1 |

Resulting data should be as below, grouping by manager or building and floor, need to generate series of number based on the number of seats.

| Manager | City | Building | Floor | Number of Seats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | BLR | SA2 | 2F | 1 |
| xxx | BLR | SA2 | 2F | 2 |
| xyz | BLR | SA2 | 2F | 3 |
| xyz | BLR | SA2 | 2F | 4 |
| xyz | BLR | SA2 | 2F | 5 |
| xya | BLR | SA2 | 3F | 1 |
| xya | BLR | SA2 | 3F | 2 |
| xjk | BLR | SA2 | 3F | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution below doesn't depend on maximum number of seats.

```
WITH 
/*
  MYTAB (Manager, City, Building, Floor, Number_of_Seats) AS
(
VALUES
  ('xxx', 'BLR', 'SA2', '2F', 2)
, ('xyz', 'BLR', 'SA2', '2F', 3)
, ('xya', 'BLR', 'SA2', '3F', 2)
, ('xjk', 'BLR', 'SA2', '3F', 1)
)
, 
*/
  T (Manager, City, Building, Floor, Number_of_Seats) AS 
(  
SELECT Manager, City, Building, Floor, Number_of_Seats 
FROM MYTAB
    UNION ALL
SELECT Manager, City, Building, Floor, Number_of_Seats - 1
FROM T
WHERE Number_of_Seats > 1
)
SELECT 
  Manager, City, Building, Floor
, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY City, Building, Floor ORDER BY Manager) AS Number_of_Seats
FROM T
ORDER BY City, Building, Floor, Manager
```

If you uncomment the commended out block and run the statement as is, you get the following output.

| MANAGER | CITY | BUILDING | FLOOR | NUMBER_OF_SEATS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | BLR | SA2 | 2F | 1 |
| xxx | BLR | SA2 | 2F | 2 |
| xyz | BLR | SA2 | 2F | 3 |
| xyz | BLR | SA2 | 2F | 4 |
| xyz | BLR | SA2 | 2F | 5 |
| xjk | BLR | SA2 | 3F | 1 |
| xya | BLR | SA2 | 3F | 2 |
| xya | BLR | SA2 | 3F | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

You would carterisan product by the no_of_seats and then order it by manager id.

Here is a way to do this

```
 with row_gen(rn) as (
        select 1 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1    
        union all
        select rn+ 1 from dummy where id < 10000 /*assumption that the number of seats isnt more than 10000*/
    )
    ,data
    as (
    select tb.mgr,tb.city,tb.bldg,tb.floor,rg.rn
      from row_gen rg
      join table tb
        on tb.no_of_seats<=rg.rn
        )
select d.mgr,d.city,d.bldg,d.floor
      ,row_number() over(partition by d.city,d.bldg,d.floor order by d.mgr) as no_of_seats
  from data d
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just fine tune to my result final query is

Answer (score 0):

```
with row_gen(rn) as (
              
  SELECT 1 AS rn FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rn+1  FROM row_gen WHERE rn+ 1 <=50
    ) 
    ,data
    as (
    select tb.manager,tb.location,tb.building,tb.floor,rg.rn
      from row_gen rg
      join db2inst1.tmp_cio_data tb
        on  rg.rn <= tb.seat_range_to
        )
select d.manager,d.location,d.building,d.floor,
     row_number() over(partition by d.location,d.building,d.floor order by d.manager) as no_of_seats
  from data d WHERE d.floor = 11 AND d.building = '12D'
```